# How to compute the Laplace transform of a normally distributed density function?

Tags: laplace-transform

I'm trying to compute the Laplace transform of a random variable $X$ with a normal density function. So $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^{2})$. This means that $f_{X} (t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}}$. Let $f(t) := f_{X} (t)$ for convenience. Then the Laplace transform $F$ amounts to: $F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} f(t) e^{-st} dt$.

Somewhere along the calculation of this integral, I get stuck. Here's what I tried so far:

\begin{align*} 
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} e^{-\frac{(t-\mu)^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} e^{-st} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\infty}  e^{- \frac{t^{2} - 2 \mu t + \mu^{2} + 2 \sigma^{2} s t}{2 \sigma^{2}} } dt\\ 
 &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \frac{t^{2} + 2t(\sigma^{2} s - \mu) + \mu^{2}}{}} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \frac{(t+(\sigma^{2}s - \mu))^{2} - (\sigma^{2} s - \mu)^{2} + \mu^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} e^{ \frac{(\sigma^{2} s - \mu)^{2} - \mu^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \frac{(t+(\sigma^{2} s - \mu))^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} dt \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^{2}}} e^{-s \mu} e^{\frac{\sigma^{2} s^{2}}{2}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{- \frac{(t+(\sigma^{2} s - \mu))^{2}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} dt
\end{align*}

At this point, I'm stuck. I don't know how to evaluate the last integral. Furthermore, when I put it in wolframalpha, it seems the result as a whole is not correct (the error function suddenly appears, which is not present in the correct result). So maybe I made a mistake along the way.

So I suppose I have two questions:

> 1. Did I make a mistake along the way? If so, which one, and how do I fix it?
> 2. If I did not make a mistake yet, how does one calculate the last integral?

Comment: What is the "correct result"?  Is it something like $\exp(-s\mu+s^2\sigma^2/2)$?  If so, it is for a bilateral Laplace transform. But if it has the normal cdf $\Phi$ buried in it, you are on the right track, as that is a repackaged error function.  As you have stated it, an error function is inevitable.

Comment: @kimchilover Yes, I think the result you mention is the correct one. Maybe the error function is indeed inevitable, but I can't figure out how it yields the correct result (and how the error function pops up exactly). I tried putting the last integral in wolframalpha with $p := sigma$ and $m := \mu$ . You can see the indefinite integral if you scroll down a bit: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5E((-(t+%2B+(p%5E(2)*s+-+m))%5E(2)%2F(2*p%5E(2)))+dt . When $t \to \infty$, then the error function is $1$ and we have $\sqrt{ \pi / 2} / \sigma $. But when $t=0$ (cont'd)...

Comment: @kimchilover we get $erf ( \frac{\mu + \sigma^{2} * s}{\sqrt{2} * \sigma} ) / \sigma $, and I don't know how to evaluate that expression.

Comment: @kimchilover ah it seems MSE couldn't parse the long link. But it's just the last integral in wolframalpha. Do you know how to proceed from here?

Comment: Well, $\erf(\cdot)$ is not an elementary function.  What one does in practice is call a computer subroutine, or approximate with an asymptotic series, or Taylor series, etc.  Or use a numerical table  printed at the back of the book.

Comment: @kimchilover alright, but there should be a way to evaluate this integral exactly and algebraically, don't you think? I mean, something similar could be done with the Fourier transform as can be seen over here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables#Using_the_convolution_theorem . The Laplace transform is not that different right?

Comment: No, I don't think that all integrals of elementary functions should have exact and algebraic evaluations.  Welcome to the real world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just do the case $\mu=0$, $\sigma=1$ and use the standard normal c.d.f. $$\Phi(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^xe^{-t^2/2}\,dt=\frac12+\frac12\mathrm{erf}(x/\sqrt 2).$$
By completing the square,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}F(s)&=&\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2/2}e^{-st}\,dt\\&=&\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac12(t^2+2st)\right)\,dt\\
&=&\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\frac12\left((t+s)^2-s^2\right)\right)\,dt\\
&=&e^{s^2/2}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_s^\infty e^{-t^2/2}\,dt\\&=&e^{s^2/2}(1-\Phi(s)).\end{eqnarray*}$$
But erf is not an [elementary function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), so it seems it cannot be simplified further.